# Use .replace() with "

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on getting data from an API, and I want to remove some characters from what it returns.

What I get back is `{"usd":323.67}`, but the currency and price may change depending on the input.

I want to remove the {}, usd (or other currency), "" and :. I searched, and found `.replace()` could be a good solution, if you replace the character with nothing. But when I use `.replace(""", "");`, I of course get an error. When I do, `.replace("{}", "");`, it doesn't replace the {} with nothing either. And because I use a constant for the currency, because the user can choose, the currency it not always the same, so I thought it could use `.replace(`${currency}`, ""), but that also doesn't work.

What should I do to remove these things from my string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Parse the returned string as JSON and your life will get a lot easier.

Comment: What @pointy said. But if you don't want to, use a single quote mark - '. i.e. `.replace('"')`, and then replace each `{` separately. But parse as json.

Comment: Could you show us how you get the data? i guess you try to do something very easy, completly overcomplicated

Comment: You probably just want to parse the JSON as @pointy said. But if you wanted to extract just the number from some not-parseable string you could use the `replace` function with a regex to keep only numerical characters. For example: `s.replace(/^[0-9\.]/g, "")`.

Comment: You probably want to use `JSON.parse(yourResponse)` or when using `fetch()` to get the data `const r = await fetch("xy"); const data = await r.json();` to parse your response as many have indicated here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others commented, parse your data as JSON and then get the value using your currency variable, something like this (not sure about what framework you are using, so the currency replacement may vary from what's shown here):

```
data = {"usd":323.67};
value = data.${currency};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find all numbers in string and then concat them with '.' symbol

```js
const getValue = (str) => str.match(/\d+/g).join('.')
console.log(getValue('{"usd":323.67}'))
console.log(getValue('{"rub":323,67p}'))
console.log(getValue('"euro":333-00'))
```